# How to Return String Array in a Mule 4 Function?

Tags: mule, dataweave

Hi  i am working on a Migration project from Spring to Mule .

In Java we have small function like

```
 private String[] getPurpose(loanPurpose){
    String purpose[] = new String[2];
    if ("REFINANCE".equalsIgnoreCase(loanPurpose)) {
        purpose[0] = "Refinance";
        purpose[1] = "Cash-Out";
        return purpose;
    } 
    return null;
}
```

In Mule i am writing it like below .

```
fun getPurpose(data) = 
if(upper("PURCHASE") == data) 
// how i can assign the values in string array and return
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[ "Refinance"," Cash-out"]`

Just create the array literal with the strings as the last value of the function. I'n this case the is the value of the true branch of `if`.

Comment: i tried it but i am getting error like shown here. Edited the question with a screen shot.

Comment: Its working in Studio , but failing in https://dwlang.fun/

Comment: If it works when executing a Mule application it is fine. That's the source of truth.

Answer (score 1):

It should work fine in studio as well. Probably the way the if value is represented could be throwing it off.. Try with the following:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

fun getPurpose(data) = 
if(upper("PURCHASE") == data) (["Refinance", "Cash-Out"]) else if (1 == 2) "abc" else "nothing"
---
getPurpose("PURCHASE")
```

Output:

```
[
  "Refinance",
  "Cash-Out"
]
```

[image: From my local DW playground]

Comment: Thanks . Yes later it worked in https://dwlang.fun/ and studio as well.